# Separate num to elements

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to 'separate' a number into `X` elements.

I mean, if my number is `12` and my desired element count (`X`) is `6`, I want to separate for each element `12/6=2`, i.e:

```
[0] = 2, [1] = 2, [2] = 2, [3] = 2, [4] = 2, [5] = 2 (Total 12)
```

if my number is `13` so `13/6=2.1666` in this case how can I separate for each elements? i.e like this:

```
[0] = 3, [1] = 2, [2] = 2, [3] = 2, [4] = 2, [5] = 2 (Total 13)
```

Or if my number is `10`, `10/6 = 1.66`

```
[0] = 2, [1] = 2, [2] = 2, [3] = 2, [4] = 1, [5] = 1 (Total 10)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is:

- create an array of length `numberOfParts`,
- repeat for `number` times,

  - increment each element of the array
  - if end the array is reached,

    - go back to the beginning of the array and increment

In code:

```
private static int[] SeparateNumber(int number, int parts) {
    var array = new int[parts];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++) {
        array[index++]++;
        if (index == parts) { // end of array reached
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

This is kind of like how you would separate a deck of cards into stacks. You deal `numberOfStacks` cards out, and then you deal cards on top of each stack sequentially, until you run out of cards.

Here is a less procedural, more functional, solution:

```
private static int[] SeparateNumber(int number, int count) {
    var remainder = number % count;
    var quotient = number  / count;
    return Enumerable.Repeat(quotient + 1, remainder)
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(quotient, count - remainder)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the number, `N`, create an array of `X` elements, each with the value of `floor(N / X)`. Now assign the units in the remainder, `R`, of `N / X` to the array cells `0...R-1` by incrementing each of their values by 1.

Example:

```
N = 10, X = 4

// array of X elements, each with the value, floor(10 / 4) = 2
array = [2, 2, 2, 2]

R = remainder 10 / 4 = 2
```

Assign the units in `R` to array cells `0..(2-1)` by incrementing their value by 1.

```
array = [3, 3, 2, 2]
```

We can, of course, avoid the increments by assigning

```
the first R cells with the value, floor(N / X) + 1

and the rest with the value, floor(N / X)
```

from the start.